# How to select form?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

A similar question already exists but **is not the same**.

I need global solution probably using directive or whatever?

I have I form

```
<form (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit>
</form>
```

Ok solution for this is not accepted for my use case:

```
submitted: false;

onSubmit(){
 this.submitted = true;
}
```

and set on button

```
[disabled]="submitted"
```

I need global solution... I start but don't know what next...

```
@Directive({ selector: 'form' })

export class PreventSubmitFewTimesDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private formSelector: ElementRef, 
  ) {}

   ngOnInit() {}  

  @HostListener('submit')
  onSubmit(evt: KeyboardEvent) { 
    .... // 
  }
```

I am target every form on submit but need best solution.

Comment: What do you wanna to achieve? Do you want to disable all submit buttons, or do you want to have the disabling behavior everywhere?

Comment: I want to forbid the submitted form from forbidding the user to click 3 times and send a request 3 times while sending the form. I want that on the form that is being submitted.

Comment: But it should be reusable for each form?

Comment: yes. On every form ...

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is the following:

```js
// Targets every form with the 'disableAfterSubmit' directive, not every form (in case you want one or two forms not to have this behavior)
@Directive({ selector: 'form[disableAfterSubmit]' })

export class PreventSubmitFewTimesDirective {

  constructor(private formSelector: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('submit')
  onSubmit(evt: KeyboardEvent) { 
    // Get the submit button with a query selector
    const button = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');
    // Disable it
    button.disabled = true;
  }
```

Note that with this solution, there is no way to re-enable the submit button.

Comment: disableAfterSubmit is probably directive which need to set in html form ?

Comment: Yes, use it like this: `<form disableAfterSubmit><!--...--><button type="submit">Submit</button></form>`. This way you can still have regular forms as well in your app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a global solution is the best approach but if you really have to do it, I would try out to save to localstorage then read from that. However i wouldn't recommend it..

Comment: A very unacceptable solution...

Comment: Yea, thats why i stated "However i wouldn't recommend it"